# not able to find ifcfg-enp0s3 in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts?

Tags: linux, networking, centos7, static-ip-address, virtual-ip-address

i want to change the IP Address of my centos7 vm which i have created in virtual box. im able to see the nic cards if i do "ifcfg". but when i go to the path /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts the nic cards are not available. can anyone help me how to change the ip in centos7. i even tried with command "setup"

[image: nic cards]

[image: list in network-scripts]

[image: Setup command]

Answer (score 3):

Create ifcfg-enp0s3 and ifcfg-enp0s8 files manually. The samples are `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/examples/networking/`. However if you use static IP address, essential items are here:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=enp0s3
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.100.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

Or if you prefer to use DHCP :

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NAME=enp0s3
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
```

Comment: This seems like the closes answer I have found but still short of what to do next. Should I create both files or 1? All I want is to have the `ifcfg-eth0` which used to work simple by editing ONBOOT to 'yes'. Now I can't find this file. I did what you asked but still have no internet connection